# Find StickNFind beacon in altbeacon library in android

Tags: android, bluetooth, altbeacon, beacon

I am using altbeacon library for android, but can't detect any StickNfind beacons.

settings of beacon layout I tried:

```
beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:0-3=4c000215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("x,s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=20,d:3-3,d:4-5,d:6-7,d:8-11,d:12-15"));
beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=00,p:3-3:-41,i:4-13,i:14-19"));
beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=10,p:3-3:-41,i:4-20v"));
beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("s:0-1=fed8,m:2-2=00,p:3-3:-41,i:4-21v"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of Stick n' Find devices is that they are not really *beacons*.  They are Bluetooth LE peripherals that advertise a connectable GATT service.  It is necessary to connect to the BLE GATT service to identify the device.

For this reason, they can't be used as beacons, which require that the unique identifier be transmitted in the Bluetooth LE advertisement.  For this reason, the Android Beacon Library will not work well for detecting Stick n' Find devices.